# Let $f(n) = 2^\sqrt{n}$ and $g \in \mathbb{R}[T] \implies g = \mathcal{O}(f)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Let $f(n) = 2^\sqrt{n}$ and $g \in \mathbb{R}[T] \implies g = \mathcal{O}(f)$.

My attempt:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g}{f(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^da_iT^i}{2^{\sqrt{n}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^da_i\frac{T^i}{2^{\sqrt{n}}} = \sum_{k=1}^d \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_iT^i}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}\right) = 0$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g}{f(n)} = 0 \implies g \leq f(n)\implies g = \mathcal{O}(f),$$

But I'm not sure if this is correct

Where can I find more exercises of this type?

Comment: Is $\mathbb R[T]$ the space of polynomials in the variable $T$?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think so. The exercise does not give that information. you think of $g(n) = \mathbb{R}[N] = \sum_{k = 0}^d a_kN^k$